# Tensorflow 1.11 hangs on "sess = tf.Session()"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I updated to TensorFlow 1.11 from 1.10 and was unable to run a health-check. The below code hangs on `sess = tf.Session()`.

Config: Windows 10 x64, latest GPU drivers, Cuda 9.0, cudnn 7.3, Python 3.6.6. This same setup used to work for TF 1.10, and all of a sudden everything stopped.

Did anybody else encounter a similar situation?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def tftest(a, b):
    # Create 100 phony x, y data points in NumPy, y = x * 0.1 + 0.3
    x_data = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
    y_data = x_data * a + b

    # Try to find values for W and b that compute y_data = W * x_data + b
    # (We know that W should be 0.1 and b 0.3, but TensorFlow will
    # figure that out for us.)
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], -1.0, 1.0))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
    y = W * x_data + b

    # Minimize the mean squared errors.
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - y_data))
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

    # Before starting, initialize the variables.  We will 'run' this first.
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    # Launch the graph.
    sess = tf.Session()   #<< the script hangs here!
    sess.run(init)

    # Fit the line.
    for step in range(201):
        sess.run(train)
        if step % 20 == 0:
            print(step, sess.run(W), sess.run(b))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tftest(20, 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's [this bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18652). The issue is still open, seems to be related to an issue in Eigen when built with MSVC.

The good news is that TensorFlow does not hang indefinitely: one has to wait for 3-4-5 minutes and then the codes resumes. This only happens once, on first startup of TensorFlow.